# Failing to find/package/reference method

Tags: .net, f#, .net-standard

I'm currently trying to build an application, and have included some dependencies (namely [Forest](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Forest/), which depends on [Texta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Texta/)). Full disclosure that I wrote both of those packages.

Texta is used by [Forest.ConsoleWriter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Forest/) to colorize the output. If I add Texta directly to a project from Nuget, it works perfectly.

```
let text = Texta.blue("Hello, World!")
printfn "%s" text
```

results in some blue text showing up in my console.

However, as soon as I try to use `ConsoleWriter` in another application, I get a runtime crash:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, string>.Texta.get_blue()

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically `MissingMethodException` indicates that the assembly being loaded is of a different version than the intended one.

One possible fix to this problem is to include the folder with the correct assemblies using `#I @"directory\assemblies"` directive(s) before the `#r @"...\...\.dll"` directives.

Many times is hard to figure out exactly what is going on behind the scenes when .Net is loading assemblies. 
So if the prior suggestion doesn't work for you, you can use the program `FUSLOGVW.exe` (run as Administrator) to log the assembly load events and view what is going on. In Windows you can find it in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools`

Comment: The method in question has been a part of Texta since the first release. I have also tried on another machine which has never seen this project (a windows one) and I get the same problem - there would be no way of the wrong assembly loading there, right? Only one of the assemblies could have ever been there.

Comment: Try `FUSLOGVW.exe` it has helped me many times in the past to understand what is going on.

Comment: It's quite possibly a wrong version of FSharp.Core, not of Texta, which makes the runtime fail to find the `FSharpFunc` return type.

Comment: I've absolutely no idea how to use `fuslogvw` - I opened it, then ran the same commands in a fresh `cmd` and got the same error, but there was nothing in `fuslogvw`'s window.

@Tarmil is it possible to see which one is being loaded/which one is being expected?

Comment: Once you open FUSLOGVW (as Administrator) go to Settings and select: Log all binds to disk. Then run your script or command. Go back to FUSLOGVW  click on refresh and you wil see the list of assemblies loaded. Double click on one and it will show you a detailed report of the load event. Use `Refresh` and `Delete all` to see the deltas as you execute the commands.